# identity theorem to prove/disprove the existence of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f$ the unit disk $\{z :|z|<1 \}$ such that
$f(\frac{1}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{2^n} $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I know by identity theorem we can prove that $f$ not exists with $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{2^n} $ but not sure if this inequality can change the conclusion.

Comment: The zero function satisfies the inequality for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: How do you know that $f(1/n)$ is real?

Comment: $f(\frac 1n)$ is complex, so the inequality is also not well posed.

Comment: @mjw it is given by the question if this holomorphic satisfies this condition. For the your function, is that function unique?

Comment: As you wrote, any constant function $f \equiv k\in (-\infty, 0]$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $|f(\frac1n)|\le \left(\frac12\right)^n$? Otherwise every holomorphic $f$ which is negative on $(-1,1)$ is a solution, e.g. $f(z)=-z^2$

Comment: @Caffeine so there is no unique function, right? but if the absolute values show on the left side then the zero function is the only function satifies the condition, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the conjecture of @mjw is right, here a tentative proof. Let me now if there are mistakes.

The zero-function satisfies the conditions, and looking for a contradiction,
let $f$ be a non-zero holomorphic function satisfying the condition too. The function $f$must have a zero of order $m\in\mathbb N_{>0}$ in $z=0$, hence
$g(z):=f(z)/z^m$ is also holomorphic and $g(0)\neq 0$. On the other hand, it holds
$$|g(0)|= \lim_{n\to \infty}|g(1/n)|=\lim_{n\to \infty} |n^m f(1/n)|\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^m}{2^n}=0$$
a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Conjecture:  The function $f(z)=0$ suggested by @Desperado is the unique holomorphic function that satisfies $$|f(1/n)| \le \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Comment: Can we prove this? I believe we only need to pass the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ to get the zero function.

Comment: I guess the conjecture of @mjw is right. I wrote up an answer.

Comment: @math_for_ever, passing to the limit you only get $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Desperado. Thank you ! I used this answer to prove that no such $f$ satisfies the condition if it is equality instead of the inequality. But what if there is no absolute value at the condition?

Comment: @math_for_ever If you drop the absolute value there are infinitely many solutions as commented above.

Comment: I see!
Thank you again!