# Non existence of analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

How to prove that there is no non constant analytic function $f$ on open unit disc with center at zero such that

$$|f(\frac{1}{n})|<\frac{1}{2^n}, n\in\mathbb N, n\geq 2$$

I tried by Identity theorem but fail to apply it as function is not given exact equal to another value . By given conditions I only know that $f(z)=z^mg(z)$ type function. Then $$|2^mf(\frac{1}{n})|< |g(\frac{1}{n})| $$ Now I am stuck.
Thank you.

Comment: $g$ is supposed to be analytic and non-zero in a neighborhood of $0$ so for all $n$ large enough $n^{-m} \left\vert g\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)\right\vert \lt 2^{-n}$ which implies what about $g(0)$?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3221059/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4028062/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Cf(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D)%7C%3C%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5En%7D%24%2C%20AND%20tags%3Acomplex-analysis)